# Emailing Third-Party Users of a Customer

Tags: bulk-email

Here is our scenario: **MyCompany** is contracted to mail physical paper packets to **CustomerCompany**'s employees. Some of those packets were incorrect. We now need to send an email to all of those employees with a PDF attachment correcting the issue, about 200 emails. **CustomerCompany** provided us a list of email addresses. The users have not explicitly opted in to any emails from us and most employees probably don't know who **MyCompany** is.

**Questions:**

1. Are we at an increased risk of being flagged a spam as users aren't expecting emails from us? We might use a separate email service if that is the case, as to not reduce our reputation.
2. Is this bad practice and/or unlawful, given that the employees haven't explicitly opted in to anything? I understand there are Opt-In laws, but I feel it doesn't apply because these are not marketing emails.